# Pentaho kettle transformation - Empty CSV file input step skip subsequent steps

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a kettle transformation which has a csv file input step. I would like the transformation to just skip all the subsequent steps in the transformation if the csv file has no data (empty). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You will probably want to define this logic in a Job file (sequential execution in Jobs vs concurrent execution in Transformations).

Answer (score 1):

Try the step "Detect Empty Stream" and check for NULL condition for any one of the columns from the CSV.

Appending a link from PDI Wiki:
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Detect+empty+stream

Comment: In case of going for the "Get File Names" as suggested by @giogix, do ensure to discount the header row.

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise, you could use the step "Get File Names". This returns many fields, one of which is the field "size". After this you can put a "Filter rows" step that sends the flow to a "Dummy" step if the size is equale to 0.